# How to avoid suspended apps getting killed in iOS 14?

Tags: applications, ipados, multitasking

I have updated my iPad operating system from iOS 11.4 to iPadOS 14.3. Unfortunately, suspended apps are now immediately killed in the background while in the older version I could keep many apps suspended in the background without need to be restarted when being used again (Even, Safari often refreshes open tabs when I want to use them after a short while during which they were not active; such a thing has also happened on the older OS, but with much less frequency).

One might expect such a <del>bug</del> for non-Apple apps because of non-compatibility with the new OS update, but it really surprised me that such a problem exists with Apple apps such as Safari and Pages.

It is really annoying, especially when you are writing some post on a Stack Exchange network and need to use some other app. I wonder whether this can be avoided somehow.

PS: It is worth saying that my iPad has enough free memory, more than that when running the older OS.

Comment: Which iPad do you have? (model, year)

Comment: @jksoegaard iPad 6th generation Wi-Fi

Comment: This also happens on my iphone 13 pro with ios 14

Answer (score -1):

#### Enable Background App Refresh

For this, you will need to go to **Settings** > **Background App Refresh** and enable Background App Refresh. You can enable/disable it for specific apps.

It will continually update the app when running in the background, making it less likely to crash/reload.

But this might not quite fix the problem if you have or too much windows opened or too many Safari tabs opened. The only method for this is to close app windows and close Safari tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as I highlighted in the OP, my concern mainly involved using the apps Safari, which seems to have the "background App Refresh" enabled by default, and Pages, which I checked has this property enabled, too. By the way, I have somewhat overcome the problem by restarting the device occasionally; it seems that doing that would reorganize the device's storage.

Comment: @Later your problem can also happen if you have too much apps opened at the same time or if you have lots of tabs opened in Safari. Even if background app refresh is enabled for Safari, if there's too much tabs opened, it will most likely reload/crash when you come back to it.